# calculating the amount of cupcakes per person

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c,peo,pie,rem_pie;
    pie = (int) c/peo;
    rem_pie = (int) c%peo;

    printf("Enter number of cupcakes:");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    printf("Enter number of people:");
    scanf("%d",&peo);
    printf("Everyone will get %d pieces.",&pie);
    printf("\nThere are %d remaining pieces.",&rem_pie);

}
```

After I put 21 as c and 5 as peo the answer just messed up and I don't know which part I do wrong.

This is the result I got from it:

[image]

Comment: Where have you learned to write this code?

Comment: C is a procedural language. Statements are executed in the order specified in the code. So the statement `pie = (int) c/peo;` needs to be after the two `scanf`.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings. Compile with `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: Why are you casting the result of the calculations?

Comment: I have tried changing the position but the answer is still the same

Comment: First of all I'm upvoting because I see this wrong understanding a lot. Let me explain in my answer.

Comment: Always, **always** check the return value of `scanf()`. If your user does enter something other than numbers, you are using your variables uninitialized (-> undefined behavior).

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks! Now, I no longer have these kind of problem but I got blocked on asking questions so I'm trying to improve my old questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So hoping this clears things up:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  // None of those variable habe any value jet.
  // They are filled with what ever random garbage was in memory at this point.
  // BAD int c, peo, pie, rem_pie;
  // If you want to make sure they are properly filled try to give them     an initial value:
  int c = 0,
  peo = 0,
  pie = 0,
  rem_pie = 0;

  // If you would calculate with them now nothing good would come out of it.
  // Because now they are either still zero or filled with crap like in your case
  // BAD pie = (int) c/peo;
  // BAD rem_pie = (int) c%peo;

  // Let the user fill them first

  printf("Enter number of cupcakes: "); // Lets also put a space between output ent input
  scanf("%d", &c);
  printf("Enter number of people: "); // same here
  scanf("%d", &peo);
  // In those cases you are putting an & befor the values to give the address in memory to the scanf function
  // that means you are not passing in the variable rather than passing in the location where to put the entered values.
  // keep this in mind for later when using printf

  // Now the variables have the right values and are ready for calculation
  // If you want to know the remaining cupcakes that means they shouldn't be split up.
  // So take them away first.
  // Example:
  // 5 cupcakes and 2 persons
  // Each person could eat 2 and a half cupcakes
  // No cupcakes left
  // But im guessing you would like to only give full cupcakes to each person
  // that means 1 cupcake left 2 for each person
  // the calculation is: (5 - 1) / 2
  // Or: (cupcakes - remaining_cupcakes)  / persons
  // You can calculate like this:

  rem_pie = c % peo;
  pie = (c - rem_pie) / peo;

  // Now when using printf you need to pass over the values
  // Not the variable memory address unlike using scanf
  // Thats means shouldn't put an & befor that.
  printf("Everyone will get %d pieces.\n", pie);
  printf("There are %d remaining pieces.\n", rem_pie);
  // Lets also put the line breaks at the end of each line to make the output a bit nicer ;)

  // Also your main function is returning an int so lets return an int zero to tell our parent programm that there are no errors.
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check those `scanf()` return codes, please...

Comment: @DevSolar pardon me? What do you mean?

Comment: If you have e.g. a `scanf( "%d", &x )`, and the user enters something that is not a number, `scanf()` **fails**. The input remains un-read (making subsequent `scanf( "%d", ... )` fail as well), and the variables in question do not get any value written to them. If you haven't initialized them beforehand, you'd be working on uninitialized variables (undefined behavior). Your code here would run into a division by zero (`peo`). Because of all this, a "naked" `scanf()` (without checking the return value, i.e. how many conversions were successful) is considered a strong code smell. (t.b.c.)

Comment: (ctd.) Good code would check the return code (`if ( scanf( "%d", &x ) != 1 )`), and then probably read and discard input until a `'\n'` is encountered and retry. Or exit with error message.

Comment: Thats a good point and I agree. I havent included it becaus of three reasons: (1.) I didnt know xD. (2.) It was beond the scope of the question. (3.) I think if you write terminal IO applications you shouldn't use naked scanf or cin functions. You should write a input function that not just checks if the inserted string is a valid number but also validates it to a fitting range and outputs error messages that fit the desired task like: "That is no number", "Please only enter positiv values" and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You calculate before the initialization. `c` and `peo` do not have a proper value *yet* when you use them in your formula. Suggestion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c,peo,pie,rem_pie;

    printf("Enter number of cupcakes:");
    if (scanf("%d", &c) != 1)
    {
        /* Handle the error. */
    }
    printf("Enter number of people:");
    if (scanf("%d", &peo) != 1)
    {
        /* Handle the error. */
    }
    pie = c/peo;
    rem_pie = c%peo;
    printf("Everyone will get %d pieces.",pie);
    printf("\nThere are %d remaining pieces.",rem_pie);

}
```

Comment: I have tried doing it but it's still the same.

Comment: @WWoPPoWW have you pasted the code into your file, built it and executed it? If so, what happened exactly? What did your output display? Can you edit the question with your tries and outputs?

Comment: yes I copied all of it and the result is still the same like in the picture I just edited in

Comment: @WWoPPoWW the first thing to check is whether the code changes you have made run at all. Temporarily replace `rem_pie = c%peo;` to `rem_pie = 2;` and see whether it displays `2` in the second output line. If so, then something is wrong with the code. If not, then apparently the change is not applied for some reason.

Comment: After I changed to 2 the result is still the same.

Comment: @WWoPPoWW If it does not change when you change the code, then you're probably not running the code you think.

Comment: @WWoPPoWW then you have an issue with building the code. You need to save the code, build it and run it. Please find out why your code is not properly built and fix that issue as well. Keep `rem_pie = 2;` for the time being just to be sure that when it works you will obviously know it by the result. Once it displays 2, change it back to `rem_pie = c%peo;` and see whether the suggested code solves the problem.

Comment: Check those scanf() return codes, please...

Comment: @DevSolar can you elaborate how you would prefer to handle the case when the result differs from 1? I have not worked in C for quite a while.

Comment: @LajosArpad: That depends. From a simple `assert( scanf( ... ) == 1 )` that avoids a silent UB but does not help in a production environment over "drop all input and repeat" all the way to chained `if`'s or a `do { ... } while ( 0 )` with failed inputs leading to a `break`. (The latter is useful if your function is allocating resources that need to be released).

Comment: @DevSolar edited my code, but I did not implement the actual handling of the error, because it's unclear how it should be handled in this case.